# Pandas dataframe row to csv row doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was using code from this site ([Pandas CSV output only the data in a certain row (to_csv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413741/pandas-csv-output-only-the-data-in-a-certain-row-to-csv))
to write a dataframe row to a csv row:

`df.iloc[-1].to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)`

but the result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

instead of

`1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

What is wrong here?

I want to make this work with df.to_csv and I've tried a few options. I know I could use different code such as `with open(...)` but the open() function conflicts with another list variable that I cannot change.

Comment: try df.iloc[:-1].  what is output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your solution, you are getting pd.Series so you cant get the desired result. But the below solution will return you a pd.DataFrame row, so i think you can get what you want.

```
df.iloc[-1:].to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

`df.iloc[-1]` gives you a `pd.Series` whose separate value is analogues to `pd.DataFrame` row with a single column, and that's how it's exported into your output csv (each value on a separate line).
To get the expected result you need to transform your `Series` into a `DataFrame` with one record/row and that's could be achieved in 2 ways:

- "long" way: `pd.DataFrame(columns=df.iloc[-1].index, data=[df.iloc[-1]]).to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`
- short way: `df.iloc[-1].to_frame().T.to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)`